# Querying dynamodb on mobile client vs backend query and response via api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am querying my contacts to match a list of contacts (primary keys) on dynamodb to see if any are using my service.

I have two options to go about this:

1) client side: I call the aws sdk directly in my mobile device and handle the response accordingly.

2) via API Gateway: I send a json of my contacts to my backend (aws lambda), which computes off client and responds via json.

I am wondering what are the pros and cons of each, or if one is clearly better?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Like many things, it depends. I don't think one is clearly better than the other.

*1 client side sdk is good because it's probably the easiest and quickest way to get going and less to build/configure/maintain.

*2 API gateway is good because it will probably be easier to call your lambda from different clients(browsers, other services,etc) and those clients wouldn't need to depend on the SDK, they could just use RESTful calls if that's how you set it up. You would also be able to support different content-types with a mapping template such as XML, YAML, etc.

It really just comes down to your use case, style, plans for reuse in the near future. You could probably start with #1 and migrate to #2 if you find you need more of the API Gateway features.